# What's the advantage of fast enumeration versus a c style for loop in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, loops

I've been using c style enumeration in objective C when I need to know at which index the object is. However, apple recommends a different style.
So, they recommend that:

```
for(int i=0;i<array.count;i++)
    NSLog(@"Object at index %i is: %@", i, array[i]);
```

be changed to

```
int index = 0;
for (id eachObject in array) {
   NSLog(@"Object at index %i is: %@", index, eachObject);
   index++;
}
```

Is there a good reason for this other than stylistic preference?

And a follow up: How would one enumerate the letters in a String using the second kind of enumeration?

Comment: array.count, than array.lenght?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A while back [someone analyzed](http://darkdust.net/writings/objective-c/nsarray-enumeration-performance) the different enumeration options for an NSArray. The results are very interesting. It's worth noting that the tests were done on iOS4 and OSX 10.6 though.

http://darkdust.net/writings/objective-c/nsarray-enumeration-performance

In general, he shows that when dealing with something other than very small arrays, fast enumeration is better performing than block enumeration, and both are better performing than basic enumeration (`array[i]`).

It would be great to see these tests on iOS7!

Answer (score 1):

Fast enumeration, the second option, can be better optimized by the compiler. So besides resulting in cleaner looking code that doesn't have to track the index, you also end up with faster code. So any time the second option would work, it likely should be used.

Now if you wanted to iterate over the characters in an `NSString`, you couldn't by default do that using fast enumeration. The only way you could do it is if you first put the characters into an `NSArray`, most likely using a standard `for` loop to iterate over the characters and add them manually. But this would defeat the purpose of using fast iteration in the first place since you have to do a standard for loop first anyway. You would only do this if you wanted to do fast iteration over this same string of text many many times, and could add them to an array first just once.

Answer (score 0):

The advantage is simply that it's faster to write and easier to read. It's especially useful when you don't need the index (i for example) other than for accessing the object.

Comment: So, I understand the advantage when you don't need the index. But what's the difference when you do? just preference?

Comment: it can also performs faster than old fashioned loops, since pointers are gotten from the array in batches rather than calling the array once per iteration.

Comment: and how about the follow up? How would you enumerate the characters in a String? what is the correct enumeration to use then?

Comment: I would suggest [`enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:) in favor of each of these. The bonus is that `NSArray`, `NSSet`, and `NSDictionary` all support this. If you need concurrent or reversal, you can use `enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:` instead. It will use fast enumeration to do this and also is the only way to enumerate `NSDictionary` getting the key and value together.

Comment: @SiLo you overtook me about few seconds, dude. Also, `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` is pretty much faster of these.

Comment: Right, I understand the enumerateObjectsUsingBlock . It is like the lambda function in python. However, my problem stands when I need to, for example, get each character from an NSString, one char at a time. That would mean my code would *need* to have c-style for loops. I guess I'm looking for the syntax that will give more uniformity to my code, unless efficiency is compromised.

Comment: @fiacobelli if you were doing one character at a time from an `NSString` then getting the `unichar` array and iterating through that C-style would be most efficient; strings are willing to give you their contents as a C array so are slightly different again.

Comment: I would recommend against `characterAtRange:` and instead iterate through the `const char*` returned by `UTF8String`. In either case you will not be able to use fast enumeration.